# hashCode(), equals(Object) and compareTo(Class)

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode, compareto

I've following the following Vertex class and it implements equals, hashCode and compareTo method. Even then my HashMap returns null. I don't know why?

```
public class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {
    int id;

    public Vertex(int number) {
        id = number;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        else if (other.getClass() != this.getClass())
            return false;
        else {
            Vertex copy = (Vertex) other;
            if (copy.id == this.id)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    public int hasCode() {
        int prime = 31;
        int smallPrime = 3;
        int hashCode = this.id ^ smallPrime - prime * this.hasCode();
        return hashCode;
    }

    public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
        if (this.id < other.id)
            return -1;
        else if (this.id > other.id)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: BTW, representing an ID as an `int` is not a good idea.

Comment: why is it not a good idea to have an id as int?

Comment: @Bozho I prefer `String` (or `long` if you insist for number), the ID could sometimes exceed the MAX_VALUE of an int. (e.g 2147483648)

Comment: It rarely does. If it does, then use `long`. Or UUID.

Comment: @codeMan `other instance of Vertex` is not required cause `Comparable<T>` is type-safe

Comment: @Bozho Depends on your country :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun Thanks for the suggestion but I had made sure that I don't exceed the limit and also another reason being I don't want to switch back and forth between string and number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is called `hasCode()`. Make it `hashCode()` instead.

I'd suggest using your IDE to automatically generate `hashCode()` and `equals(..)`. That will generate the proper methods (right now you have a recursive call in `hashCode()`)

Comment: ... and then remove the recursive call.

Comment: @Bozho I made a really bad mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in your `equals()` method

```
else if(other.getClass()!=this.getClass())
        return false;
```

can be changed to

```
else if(!(other instanceof Vertex))
        return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this based on what Integer does. Note: the use of `@Override` would have shown you were overriding the wrong method.

```
public class Vertex {
    final int id;
    public Vertex(int number){
        id = number;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        if(!(other instanceof Vertex)) return false;

        return ((Vertex)other).id == id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return id; }
}
```